# Dividing $9x^2+5x+1$ by $2x-6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$
> \require{enclose}
> \begin{array}{rll}
>    2x-6 \enclose{longdiv}{9x^2+5x+1}\end{array}
> $$

Does $9x^2+5x+1$ have a root of $x-3$? I am trying to simplify this equation.

Comment: Try plugging in three (to the top polynomial). That is, does $x=3$ satisfy $9x^2+5x+1=0$. If so that was easy, if not you will need to use either synthetic division or long division.

Comment: Use the Polynomial Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Plugging x=3 into 9x^2+5x+1=97,   using long division results in 9x+32 with a Remainder of 95

Comment: The remainder is 97 not 95. I think you subtracted rather than added.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the process of long division, you find that $9x^2 + 5x + 1 $ divided by $x - 3$ gives you  $9x + 32$ with a remainder of 97 so $x - 3$ is NOT a root of $9x^2 + 5x + 1 $.

Another way of checking would be plugging in the value, $x = 3$; we do this after setting the original polynomial ($9x^2 + 5x + 1 $) to $0$  in order to form the **associated polynomial equation**. Using the associated polynomial equation, any values of $x$ that results in $0$ is a root of the original polynomial.  In this case, plugging in $x = 3$ does NOT equal $0$ so, again, $x = 3$ is NOT a root.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have showed you how to work this out using synthetic division.

Firstly 2X - 6 cannot be equal to 0.
Therefore, X cannot be equal to 3.

Now we take that 3 and use it in our synthetic division as a multiplier.

As you can see the quotient is 9X + 32 and the remainder is 97.

Since the remainder is not 0 therefore X-3 is not a root.

[image]

Comment: Note that you essentially factored out a $2$ to get that quotient, so you have to multiply back in a $\frac 12$.  That is, you found that $$9x^2+5x+1 = (9x+32)(x-3)+97$$ But you need to factor a $2$ out of the $(9x+32)$ to put it back in the $(x-3)$, giving you $$9x^2+5x+1 = \left(\frac{9}{2}x + 16\right)(2x-6)+97$$